# Eliminar Valores de Multiselect Select 2 y BD MySql al mismo tiempo PHP CODEIGNITER

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select2

estoy haciendo un sistema en PHP CodeIgniter usando MVC, el detalle es que tengo formulario con varios Multiselect(hecho con Select2) y al momento de querer editar los campos registrados, cuando tengo un multi select como se ve en la imagen y quiero eliminar una opcion y darle actualizar, no me actualiza la bd o sea no me elimina ese dato en la BD que elimine en el Select 2[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia de como debo hacerlo?

les anexo mi codigo en el Modelo en donde hago los Update:

```
        public function savebp($data,$data2){

          $resultado = $this->db->insert("tb_proyectos",$data);

          $last_id=$this->db->insert_id(); 

          $id_additional_contact = $data2;

          $array_add = explode(",", $id_additional_contact);

                        for($i=0;$i<count($array_add);$i++) { 



                        $resultado2 = $this->db->query(" insert into tb_detalle_proyectos(id_proyecto,id_contact) values($last_id,$array_add[$i])");

                                                                                        }

       return array($resultado,$resultado2);




                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás mandando las variables de PHP directamente en la consulta.

Intenta con esto:

```
public function savebp($data, $data2)
{
    $resultado = $this->db->insert("tb_proyectos", $data);
    $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $id_additional_contact = $data2;
    $array_add = explode(",", $id_additional_contact);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_add); $i++)
    {
        $resultado2 = $this->db->query("
        insert into tb_detalle_proyectos(id_proyecto,id_contact) 
        values(".$last_id.",".$array_add[$i].")");
    }

    return array(
        $resultado,
        $resultado2
    );
}
```

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, muchas gracias por tu aporte.... La solucion fue que al momento de actualizar doy un delete y luego un insert para que asi guarde en tiempo real.

Answer (score 0):

public function update($id,$data,$data2,$id_detalle){

```
            $this->db->where('id_proyecto',$id);
            $resultado = $this->db->update('tb_proyectos',$data);

            $id_additional_contact = $data2;                    




            $resultado2 = $this->db->query("Delete from tb_detalle_proyectos where id_proyecto= $id");

                if(!is_null($id_additional_contact)){

                     $array_edit = explode(",", $id_additional_contact);

                if(is_null($id_detalle)){



                                         for($i=0;$i<count($array_edit);$i++) { 






                            $resultado3 = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tb_detalle_proyectos(id_proyecto,id_contact) select $id,$array_edit[$i] from dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id_contact FROM tb_detalle_proyectos WHERE id_contact = $array_edit[$i] and id_proyecto=$id) LIMIT 1;");


                             $id_detalle =   $id_detalle + 1;



                                                                                        }


                }
                else{



                        for($i=0;$i<count($array_edit);$i++) { 

                    $resultado3 = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tb_detalle_proyectos(id_proyecto,id_contact) select $id,$array_edit[$i] from dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id_contact FROM tb_detalle_proyectos WHERE id_contact = $array_edit[$i] and id_proyecto=$id) LIMIT 1;");

                        }

                }

                                        }


       return array($resultado,$resultado2,$resultado3);                    




}
```

Esta fue mi solucion.